# How to pass jenkins param value in a java constant

Tags: java, jenkins, gradle

I have a test project that is running on a `CI (Jenkins)` against an `UAT env`. I would like to extend this project to run against other envs like `dev env` or `performance env`. I define the `UAT env endpoint` in a constant in an utility class. I would like to parameterize the Jenkins build so that when an env is selected the proper endpoint would be used in tests either coming from a property file or straight as a value from Jenkins params. I have trouble in identifying an approach to make this work. Any approaches would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple approaches . If you have jenkins file in the project you can have a parameter

```
pipeline{

parameters{
   choice(name: 'ENV',choices:"test\nprod",description:"select environment")

}
environmet{

env = "${params.ENV}"
}
```

and you can use this variable in different stages . like:

```
stage{

agent ...
when{environment name : "env",value:"test"}{
```

or you can read the property file as well in jenkins file and make use of it . I prefer the above way as i can decide before the deployment which param to pass